# AppDelegate.swift line 0 type metadata accessor for _ContiguousArrayStorage<String> crash

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

There is a strange crash happening in my code when I try upgrade the app version.

Here is the crash report for the crash :-

```
  Crashed: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
  0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x102f6f95c specialized _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 164
  1  Quickride                      0x1011b02f8 type metadata accessor for _ContiguousArrayStorage<String> (AppDelegate.swift)
  2  Quickride                      0x1011a1cfc closure #1 in closure #1 in AppDelegate.persistentContainer.getter (AppDelegate.swift)
  3  Quickride                      0x1015196cc thunk for @callee_owned (@owned NSPersistentStoreDescription, @owned Error?) -> () (UserDataCache.swift)
  4  CoreData                       0x184f3d6d0 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _doAddPersistentStoreWithDescription:privateCopy:completionHandler:] + 920
  5  CoreData                       0x184f3d8a0 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithDescription:completionHandler:] + 172
  6  CoreData                       0x18500100c -[NSPersistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:] + 484
  7  Quickride                      0x1011a1c6c AppDelegate.persistentContainer.getter (AppDelegate.swift:670)
  8  Quickride                      0x10123a72c specialized static  CoreDataHelper.getNSMangedObjectContext() (CoreDataHelper.swift:18)
  9  Quickride                      0x101131664 specialized static ContactPersistenceHelper.clearAllContacts() (ContactPersistenceHelper.swift:113)
  10 Quickride                      0x10123efd0 specialized UserModuleSessionManager.clearUserPersistentStore() (UserModuleSessionManager.swift:103)
  11 Quickride                      0x1010417d4 specialized QRSessionManager.performSessionChangeOperationOnModule(moduleSessionHandler:sessionChangeOperationId:) (QRSessionManager.swift)
  12 Quickride                      0x10103df24 QRSessionManager.callSessionChangeOperationOnAllModules(sessionChangeOperationId:isShutdownSequence:) (QRSessionManager.swift:256)
  13 Quickride                      0x10103d410 QRSessionManager.onResumeUserSession() (QRSessionManager.swift:159)
  14 Quickride                      0x1013125b0 SessionManagerController.resumeUserSession(sessionChangeCompletionListener:) (SessionManagerController.swift:82)
  15 Quickride                      0x10128b0c8 closure #1 in AppStartupHandler.resumeUserSessionAndNavigateToAppropriateInitialView() (AppStartupHandler.swift:38)
  16 Quickride                      0x100ee5784 thunk for @callee_owned () -> () (RideManagementModuleSessonHandler.swift)
  17 libdispatch.dylib              0x181e50aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
  18 libdispatch.dylib              0x181e50a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
  19 libdispatch.dylib              0x181e5ddfc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 924
  20 libdispatch.dylib              0x181e5d9fc _dispatch_worker_thread3 +       120
  21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182183fac _pthread_wqthread + 1176
  22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182183b08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Any help guys on whats this strange crash all about ? Tried a lot but couldn't figure you..... Thanks in advance

Comment: Did your data model change? If so, did you add a new version for the data model and setup automatic migration?

Comment: @Yonat I have done all the neccesary changes like adding new data model version and mapping files for migration and all. How to set up the automatic migration?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_lightweight_migration . Basically you want `addPersistentStore()` to get the options: `[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]`

Comment: @Yonat I have done all the  changes like creating mapping models and adding these options you have mentioned above but still this crash happens.